# Question involving partial derivative of a function $f : \Omega \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, partial-derivative, lebesgue-measure

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be an open set, $f:\Omega\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, and assume that the functions $x\mapsto f\left(x,\omega\left(x\right)\right)$ are $L^{1}\left(\Omega\right)$ for all $\omega\in L^{2}\left(\Omega\right)$.  Assume that $\exists g\in L^{2}\left(\Omega\right)$ such that $\left|\dfrac{\partial f\left(x,t\right)}{\partial t}\right|\leq g\left(x\right), \forall x\in\Omega$, where we've defined

$$\dfrac{\partial f\left(x,t\right)}{\partial t}:=\lim_{t'\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{f\left(x,t+t'\right)-f\left(x,t\right)}{t'}$$

Suppose $u,v\in L^{2}\left(\Omega\right)$.  Prove that:

$$\lim_{t\rightarrow0}{\displaystyle \int_{\Omega}}\dfrac{f\left(x,u\left(x\right)+tv\left(x\right)\right)-f\left(x,u\left(x\right)\right)}{t}dx={\displaystyle \int_{\Omega}\dfrac{\partial f\left(x,u\left(x\right)\right)}{\partial t}v\left(x\right)dx}$$

I would like some hints.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: find a way to use given inequality with DCT.

Comment: @MarcinŁoś What is DCT?

Comment: @chuyenvien94 Dominated Convergence Theorem

Comment: Why can use DCT, we don't have a sequence of functions?

Comment: Yes, we don't have a sequence, but the topology of real numbers have some particulary helpful property ;) Hint: think about Heine definition of limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding upon my comments, here is a complete, detailed solution.

Since we have

$$
\left|\frac{\partial f(x, t)}{\partial t}\right|\leq g(x)
$$

for all $x\in\Omega$, $f$ is differentiable in second variable, and so by Mean Value Theorem for each $x\in\Omega$, $t < t'\in\mathbb{R}$ there exists $t_0$ such that

$$
\left|\frac{f(x, t + t') - f(x, t)}{t}\right| = \left|\frac{\partial f(x, t_0)}{\partial t}\right| \leq g(x)
$$

Thus, the quotient is dominated by $g(x)$. It follows that

$$
\left|\frac{f(x, u(x) + t v(x)) - f(x, u(x))}{t}\right|\leq \left|v(x)\right|\, g(x)
$$

Now, since both $v(x), g(x)$ are $L^2$, their product is $L^1$.

Furthermore,

$$
\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(x, u(x) + t v(x)) - f(x, u(x))}{t} = 
\frac{\partial f(x, t)}{\partial t}v(x)
$$

Let us now take any sequence $t_n \to 0$. By Dominated Convergence Theorem,

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_\Omega \frac{f(x, u(x) + t_n v(x)) - f(x, u(x))}{t_n} dx =\\
=\int_\Omega \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(x, u(x) + t_n v(x)) - f(x, u(x))}{t_n} dx =\\
=\int_\Omega \frac{\partial f(x, t)}{\partial t}v(x)\,dx
$$

as the quotient is dominated by $\left|v(x)\right|\,g(x) \in L^1$. Since it holds for all sequences $t_n\to 0$, we conclude the limit as $t\to 0$ exists and is equal to this integral.